# How do I use function from external library?

Tags: c++, c, cmake, execute

I'm starting an OpenGL Application via glc-capture. glc is a c-library which hooks on the OpenGL buffer and x11 server.
glc needs a key command in the OpenGL display to start recording the OpenGL output.

But my software should start recording the output programmatically, not via a key presses.
The glc files are all too complex for my basic knowledge to understand them completely.
But basically the structur seems to be the following:

The [glc-capture](https://github.com/nullkey/glc/blob/master/scripts/capture.sh) is a shell script which does some settings and executes `LD_PRELOAD=libglc-capture.so "${@}"`. [x11.c](https://github.com/nullkey/glc/blob/master/src/hook/x11.c) contains the x11 hook which listens for key events. There are some initializations going on.
On a special key event the function `start_capture()` is executed by [x11.c](https://github.com/nullkey/glc/blob/master/src/hook/x11.c).
`start_capture()` is defined in a file [lib.h](https://github.com/nullkey/glc/blob/master/src/hook/lib.h) and implemented in the [main.c](https://github.com/nullkey/glc/blob/master/src/hook/main.c) file.

**My questions:
How can I execute the start_capture() function on my own c++ application?**
I tried link the libraries (hook and capture) via `CMakeList.txt` and include the header file, but that always leaves me at "undefined reference: start_capture()".

Here is the line from CMakeList.txt which links the libraries:

```
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${QT_LIBRARIES} libglc-hook.so libglc-capture.so libglc-core.so libglc-export.so)
```

EDIT2:
Here is the error I get at runtime:

> /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/visualization/rviz/bin/rviz: symbol lookup
>   error:
>   /home/jrick/fuerte_workspace/sandbox/Bag2Film/lib/libBag2Film.so:
>   undefined symbol: start_capture

The output from nm:

> jrick@robot2:~/fuerte_workspace/sandbox/Bag2Film/lib$ nm
>   libBag2Film.so | grep capture
>
> 0000000000003a30 t start_capture
>
> 0000000000003790 t stop_capture

Comment: Can you show the CMakeList which did the linking?

Comment: I added the line with the linking. Or do you need the hole txt file?

Comment: Are you sure you need the .so file extension?

Comment: that lib.h is not C++ safe, if you want to call something in it from C++ code, you would need to add extern "C" around it.

Comment: Yes, it doesn't compile without them.
Ah, thanks for the hint nos!

Comment: When I add the extern "C" around it everything compiles without errors.
But when I execute start_capture(); I get an symbol lookup error / undefined symbol. Any idea why this is happening?
I guess there is no implementation found of start_capture(). The linker should link that to the libraries, right?

Comment: Oki, I just saw you edited your post to include the error message, so forget my last sentence.

Comment: Do an `nm` on the libraries as well to see where `start_capture` is exported and where it is used. Then sort the libraries in your `target_link_libraries...` line so that the library that defines `start_capture` comes after all the ones that use this function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know about glc-capture, but from what you say it should be possible to linke your application directly against libglc-capture (try passing `-lglc-capture` as a linker flag). Consult the libraries documentation if that doesn't work.

In addition, you would have to include a header file that includes the declaration of `start_capture`. Again, consult the library documentation to find out about which file to use. If there's no header present, you can still declare it yourself (sounds like a C-library, so something along the line `extern "C" { void start_capture(); }` might do it.

If your project still compiles and links after these changes, add a call to `start_capture()` where you need it.

Come back here if it doesn't help.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I added the `extern "C" {int start_capture();}´ to the lib.h and removed the old include. The lib.h is included in my class.
But as soon as I execute start_capture(); I'm getting an undefined symbol error. Does the header file lib.h know where to find the implementation?

Comment: Hm... that doesn't seem right. Normally, you cannot execute a function that the linker didn't find. Does the error show up at compile time, link time or runtime? Please post the error message.

Comment: The error shows up at runtime only.
I'm not sure about how to declare the function though. For now I modified the original lib.h and put it in my src folder, adding it to my CMakeList.txt. In the lib.h I added the extern "C" to the function. Is that okay?

Comment: If you have a `lib.h` that declares `start_capture` that should be fine. You have to make sure though whether it's a C or C++ header. If it's C only and your own program is C++, you should wrap the include in `extern "C" { #include "lib.h" }`. Still, the exact error message would be helpful.

Comment: Thanks again for your help. I added the wrap around #include lib.h now, but it didn't change anything. Any other ideas?
I updated the main question with the full error.

Comment: Also when I try to get the function via dlsym, but it does not find my symbol. But still these symbols are definitely in my lib, defined as local symbols though (see main question).
Does it matter that they are local symbols instead of globals?

Comment: Any other ideas why this is happening :-/?

Comment: What do you mean by "local symbols"? Declared `static`? You cannot use a symbol that is local (aka not exported) inside another library/compilation unit. If you could, it wouldn't be local after all.

Comment: Okay, it seems like the function really is local (marked with a small t, for local).
For making it accessible I would have to change the declaration from `__PRIVATE int start_capture();` to `int start_capture();` and recompile, right?

Comment: Yes, seems so. However `__PRIVATE` is not standard, so I can't really tell.

Comment: https://github.com/nullkey/glc/blob/master/src/hook/lib.h
This is the declaration of the function. Just removing the __PRIVATE doesn't seem to be enough, `start_capture()` is still marked as local.
I'm really don't understand where this __PRIVATE is coming from and where it is declared. Any idea?

Comment: `__PRIVATE` is coming from `https://github.com/nullkey/glc/blob/master/src/glc/common/glc.h`. Just browse through the includes: `#define __PRIVATE __attribute__ ((visibility ("hidden")))`

Comment: Okay, it really was that easy. Change __PRIVATE to __PUBLIC and it all worked out.
Thanks again for your help, I really appreciate.